# CSS - stop layout from changing

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of images that are generated on the screen. The amount of images in a row on the grid depends on the size of the page. It all works well until the page gets too small, then the layout goes off.

[This is the proper layout.](http://gyazo.com/5800ffb16efec1f67aa22d13361525cc)

[This is what happens when the page gets too small.](http://gyazo.com/2cbaeb668230a7cb142da4f368830412)

CSS:

```
.g {
        padding: 0.25em;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .g li {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            background: #fff;
            background-repeat: repeat; 
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .g img {
         max-width: 100%
            display: block;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 55em) {
            .g li {
                width: 25%; 
            }
            .g li:nth-child(4n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(3n+1) {
                clear: none;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 72em) {
            .g li {
                width: 20%; 
            }
            .g li:nth-child(5n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(4n+1) {
                clear: none;
            }
        }
```

Could I make it so if the page got small than the 4x4 grid, that grid still stayed, rather than it changing?

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to:

```
.g {
        padding: 0.25em;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .g li {
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            background: #fff;
            background-repeat: repeat; 
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .g img {
         max-width: 100%
            display: block;
        }
            .g li:nth-child(5n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(4n+1) {
                clear: none;
            }
```

EDIT:

Simply remove the first media wrap.

```
.g {
        padding: 0.25em;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .g li {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            background: #fff;
            background-repeat: repeat; 
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .g img {
         max-width: 100%
            display: block;
        }

            .g li {
                width: 25%; 
            }
            .g li:nth-child(4n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(3n+1) {
                clear: none;
            }
        @media screen and (min-width: 72em) {
            .g li {
                width: 20%; 
            }
            .g li:nth-child(5n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(4n+1) {
                clear: none;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to keep all the code I have, but to add a check to see if the page is less than a certain size, and if it is keep the grid at 25% or 4 columns?

Comment: I fail to see the point in that. You are just going to cancel out code, which is the same as removing it. EDIT: Also, with your default code the width is 100% and one column. The @media tags make it 20% width.

Comment: The code that you are deleting sets the grid to have either 4 or 5 columns, deleting it removes any layout of the grid. I want to keep the 4 or 5 columns, but not have it mess up when it gets too small.

Comment: You still want it to change to 4 but not any less?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want it to do.